# How come the ball size wont increase?(Game)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an addition to a pong game framework.I want the ball size to increase everytime the ball make contact with a paddle.

Here is my attempt. The first block of code is where I think the problem lays. The 2nd block is the whole class.

```
public class PlayState extends State {
private Paddle paddleRight, paddleLeft;
private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 30;
private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 60;

private Ball ball;

//bDiam stands for ball diameter

private static int bDiam = 10;

private int playerScore = 0;
private Font scoreFont;

@Override
public void init() {
    paddleLeft = new Paddle(0, 195, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    paddleRight = new Paddle(785, 195, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    scoreFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25);
    ball = new Ball(300, 200, bDiam, bDiam);
}

@Override
public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
//  playerScore = 5;


}

@Override
public void update() {
    paddleLeft.update();
    paddleRight.update();
    ball.update();

    if (ballCollides(paddleLeft)) {
        playerScore++;

        bDiam+=  20;
        ball.onCollideWith(paddleLeft);
        Resources.hit.play();
    } else 
        if (ballCollides(paddleRight)) {
        playerScore++;
        bDiam= bDiam + 20;
        ball.onCollideWith(paddleRight);
        Resources.hit.play();
    } else if (ball.isDead()) {
        playerScore -= 3;

        ball.reset();

    }
}
```

The Complete Class

```
public class PlayState extends State {
private Paddle paddleRight, paddleLeft;
private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 30;
private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 60;

    private Ball ball;

    //bDiam stands for ball diameter

    private static int bDiam = 10;

    private int playerScore = 0;
    private Font scoreFont;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        paddleLeft = new Paddle(0, 195, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        paddleRight = new Paddle(785, 195, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        scoreFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25);
        ball = new Ball(300, 200, bDiam, bDiam);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
    //  playerScore = 5;


    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        paddleLeft.update();
        paddleRight.update();
        ball.update();

        if (ballCollides(paddleLeft)) {
            playerScore++;

            bDiam+=  20;
            ball.onCollideWith(paddleLeft);
            Resources.hit.play();
        } else 
            if (ballCollides(paddleRight)) {
            playerScore++;
            bDiam= bDiam + 20;
            ball.onCollideWith(paddleRight);
            Resources.hit.play();
        } else if (ball.isDead()) {
            playerScore -= 3;

            ball.reset();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        // Draw Background
        g.setColor(Resources.darkBlue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMain.GAME_WIDTH, GameMain.GAME_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Resources.darkRed);
        g.fillRect(GameMain.GAME_WIDTH / 2, 0, GameMain.GAME_WIDTH / 2,
                GameMain.GAME_HEIGHT);
        // Draw Separator Line
        g.drawImage(Resources.line, (GameMain.GAME_WIDTH / 2) - 2, 0, null);

        // Draw Paddles
        g.setColor(Color.white);
     g.fillRect(paddleLeft.getX(), paddleLeft.getY(), paddleLeft.getWidth(),
            paddleLeft.getHeight());
        g.fillRect(paddleRight.getX(), paddleRight.getY(),
                paddleRight.getWidth(), paddleRight.getHeight());

        // Draw Ball
        g.drawRect(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());

        // Draw UI
        g.setFont(scoreFont); // Sets scoreFont as current font
        g.drawString("" + playerScore, 350, 40); // Draws String using current
                                                    // font
    }



    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            paddleLeft.accelUp();
            paddleRight.accelUp();
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            paddleLeft.accelDown();
            paddleRight.accelDown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyRelease(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP
                || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            paddleLeft.stop();
            paddleRight.stop();
        }
    }

    private boolean ballCollides(Paddle p) {
        return ball.getRect().intersects(p.getRect());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your diameter variable is being passed by value into your Ball constructor. That means changing its value in your main program won't change it for the ball.

You need something like

```
ball.setDiameter(ball.getDiameter() +20)
```